# Element Not Found error when selecting from a drop down with Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm creating a bit of code where a user creates Sales Opportunities, which are associated with a certain company. I set up some code that was working fine when a user had to manually input the id of the company, then changed it so the form would display a list of all companies associated with that user's organization (user belongs_to organization, company belongs_to organization, sales_opportunity belongs_to both User and Company).

This has caused my Rspec/Capybara tests to fail with the following error message:

```
Failure/Error: page.select "Test Co", :from => "Company"
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find option "Test Co"
```

The relevant tests:

```
describe "sales opportunities" do
  let(:organization) { FactoryGirl.create(:organization, :name_one, :with_users)}
  let(:company) {organization.companies.create(company_name: "Test Co", organization_id: organization.id, existing_customer: true)}
  let(:user) {organization.users.first}
  before do
    sign_in user
    visit user_path(user)
  end
it 'has links to add a new sales opportunity' do
  expect(page).to have_link('Add sales opportunity', href: new_user_sales_opportunity_path(user_id: user.id))
end

it 'adds a new sales opportunity' do
page.click_link('Add sales opportunity')
page.fill_in('Opportunity name', with: "Capybara Opportunity")
page.fill_in('Close date', with: "2014/12/18")
page.fill_in('Sale value', with: 20000)
page.select "Test Co", :from => "Company"
page.click_button('Save')
expect(current_path).to eq(user_path(user))
expect(page).to have_content('Capybara Opportunity')
expect(page).to have_content('20000')
expect(page).to have_content('2014-12-18')
end
```

The form field for selecting a company:

```
      <%= f.label :company_id %><br>
  <%= f.collection_select :company_id, @user.organization.companies(:company_name), :id, :company_name %>
```

I can include other parts of the code if you think they're necessary, but from my current guess it seems the Company I'm creating with the "Let" block is not associated with my Organization/User, OR the form is not able to identify this company for some reason. I can't quite work out what I'm doing wrong here - can you help please?

Comment: Oh, and just for reference the code works fine in the browser - so it's the test that's broken rather than the underlying code as far as I can see.

Comment: Add `gem launchy` to your Gemfile, than add `save_and_open_page` just after `visit` in the spec file. It'll open the page in your browser and you can verify if the element is really there or not. Don't believe it should be there but check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I fixed this - it was related to the way I was building the company in the test suite. Instead of doing it as above, I put it into a Factory instead:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

factory :organization do
    trait :name_one do
    organization_name       "New Example Org"
    end

    trait :name_two do
        organization_name   "Any Wrong Org"
    end
    trait :with_users do
    before(:create) do |organization|
        organization.users << FactoryGirl.build(:user)
        organization.users << FactoryGirl.build(:user, name: "Second User", email: "email2@example.com")
    end
end
```

And:

```
    factory :company do
    company_name            "Test Company"
    existing_customer       "False"
    association             :organization, :name_one, :with_users
end
```

And then called it as follows in the rspec test:

```
describe "sales opportunities" do
  let(:company) {FactoryGirl.create(:company)}
  let(:user) {company.organization.users.first}
  before do
    sign_in user
    visit user_path(user)
  end
it 'has links to add a new sales opportunity' do
  expect(page).to have_link('Add sales opportunity', href: new_user_sales_opportunity_path(user_id: user.id))
end

it 'adds a new sales opportunity' do
page.click_link('Add sales opportunity')
page.fill_in('Opportunity name', with: "Capybara Opportunity")
page.fill_in('Close date', with: "2014/12/18")
page.fill_in('Sale value', with: 20000)
page.select "Test Company", :from => "Company"
page.click_button('Save')
expect(current_path).to eq(user_path(user))
expect(page).to have_content('Capybara Opportunity')
expect(page).to have_content('20000')
expect(page).to have_content('2014-12-18')
end
```

This sends all the tests green, so whilst I'm not sure what the hell I was doing wrong initially, the answer is to build using FactoryGirl.

Comment: interesting i've read some people think the entire opposite - that the use of such gems adds complications.